# Python: I have 16 cpu cores - does that mean when I run 16 Jupyter notebook, each uses one core fully?

Tags: python, performance, split, parallel-processing, jupyter-notebook

I have a large data frame, from which subsets are taken via a loop and some analysis is performed on this data. I could simply duplicate the jupyter notebook and just start the algorithm at different part of the data and then record the results, i.e. via csv locally. After that I would combine my results back again.

Does that work? or are all kernels when I open a new notebook running using only one cpu? I am using a server so in fact I can go up to 16 cores usage if necessary.

I tried to google, but most of the questions require to run the jupyter notebook where are have access and write to the same data set, which I don't necessarily need with the above mentioned walk-around.

edit: maybe to rephrase the question: does every opened jupyter notebook / kernel uses a separate cpu?

Comment: you should look into dask.dataframe  : http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html

Comment: thanks, evamicur: just had a quick look at it; i have sufficient ram to use all the data, so that is not a problem; i just need to speed up the entire process without modifying the actual (simply because I am not able to); so my question was pointing rather to a quick and dirty fix

Comment: if you can post the actual analysis code we may be able to speed it up

Comment: thank you evamicur: just not sure how to "transform" the code into an MWE here... would you know re my question above?

Comment: if you want it to run on many cores I think dask is the easiest way to do it tbh. Depending on your problem you might be able to do multiprocessing and do the analysis on multiple processes

Comment: I am not sure whether this is the right platform to post the entire code (it's very long), but your guidance is very much appreciated